# did Indrajit tell Ravana that Rama was Narayana himself?

Tags: ramayana, lakshmana, indrajit

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3zrT-ccbHM

In this (In Hindi) episode Indrajit tells Ravana that when he fired them at Lakshmana, Brahmastra, Pashupathastra and Narayana chakra only saluted Lakshmana and returned to him.

He tells Ravana that Rama and Lakshmana are not mere mortals - but Rama is Narayana himself.

Is this poetic license or is it in Valmiki Ramayana?

Comment: Looks like poetic license, as far as I remember to have read he didn't get time to meet his father before his death. Maybe the "experts here" will better answer. :)

Comment: of course !! TV serials move forward in episodes - whereas in the the actual war they would have taken a break from fighting only for the night @Vivikta

Comment: lol, I obviously know that. What I'm saying is I haven't read of any such pep talks between the father son duo. Maybe it's something on the line with Lakshmana getting sermons by Ravana, etc..@S K

Comment: even as the war was progressing, IIRC, some of his own people were telling Ravana to give up - perhaps the serializers threw this in as something that COULD have happened @Vivikta

Comment: yeah precisely. Anyway, the main Valmiki don't talk about it. But then, there are several of other *Ramayanas*,  maybe derived from others